# Genus $0$ algebraic curves integral points decidable?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, decidability

It is known there is an explicit algebraic variety in $\mathbb Z[x_1,\dots,x_t]$ a bounded $t>2$ whose integral zero-set is non-empty is undecidable.

1. If the variety has genus $0$ is there anything known about decidability?
2. If the variety has genus $0$ and $t=2$ is there anything known about decidability?

Comment: What is a variety of genus $0$?

Comment: @abx a variety whose leftmost Hodge number is zero…

Comment: ... and what is "the" leftmost Hodge number? And what do you call a "variety"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_genus

Comment: Triviality of the "outer ring of the Hodge diamond", more precisely, "Hodge coniveau $\geq 1$", is insufficient for decidability.  Just take any variety $X$ that is undecidable (as in Matiyasevich's theorem), and then consider $X\times \mathbb{P}^n$ for $n>0$.

Comment: My comment is wrong.  Only the “middle” Hodge structures of the product have positive coniveau.  Sorry!

Comment: I have seen this mistake many times. In the DPRM theorem there is no single equation/variety for which its integer solutions/points are undecidable. Either it has points or not, so either the Turing machine that always says "Yes" or the one that always says "No" is right. The DPRM theorem is about families of equations.